# Short story: in the future, only machines make music, but a man inside a computer plays the music at a concert

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence, music

I am looking for the name of a short story and its author where, in the future, only machines make music but a man inside a computer plays the music at a concert. When the crowd finds out that it wasn't the machine that made the music, they are angry. Ray Bradbury? Isaac Asimov?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you have any idea when you would have read this?  Was it online, in a magazine or an anthology?

Comment: Sounds a bit like Walter M Miller's *The Darfstelel but mthatb was nabout acting rather than music.*

Comment: It was in a book, a collection of short stories, I think, in the 1970s, maybe 1980s.